# Using a scripted expression driver to combine two angles

Tags: python, drivers

I am trying to use a driver with a scripted expression to place an object's rotation in between the rotation of two other angle-measuring objects.

So there are objects I've labeled `BeginAngle` and `EndAngle`, as well as `ResultAngle`.
I've managed to script it so that ResultAngle will be placed exactly halfway in the middle using:

```
((endangle-beginangle)/2)
```

What I really want to do is not just place it halfway but instead specify ratios in decimal like `0.333`, `0.618` etc.
My Python and math skills have proven insufficient thus far.

[image]

[.blend file here.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/686388/posts/stackexchange/python-angles.blend)

Thanks for any help!

Things to note:
Rotation along Blender's Z axis is inverted (- degrees), making this trickier. Also you may need to tick "Auto-Run Python Scripts" under *Preferences > File*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you mean that you want a "[convex combination](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/404152/112764)" of the angles, so that:

- `0` will return an angle that is just `BeginAngle`
- `0.5` will return an angle halfway between `BeginAngle` and `EndAngle`
- `0.33` will return an angle that is closer to `BeginAngle` than `EndAngle`

In that case, you can use the scripted expression:

```
(1.0 - 0.33) * BeginAngle + (0.33) * EndAngle
```

Comment: Fantastic! Elegantly simple and customizable. Exactly the sort of answer I was hoping for. Just tried it out. Thank you.